# Update errors: 404, "E: Unable to parse package file "

Tags: 11.10, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

Whenever i try to install or update anythin in ubuntu 11.10 i am getting this list of errors.

Some restricted , universal and main packages show the result failed to fetch or 404 error or check your internet connection.

I have updated several times but the problem persists.Do i have to add / remove something from my source list please help.

This is the list of errors i am getting.

http://pastebin.com/LfgXzPHv

This is my source list

http://pastebin.com/4nJwRQvP

i changed the server so now only one errors remains

E: Unable to parse package file 
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_multiverse_i18n_Index (1)

where mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in is the new mirror i am using.

Comment: Have you read line 2 of your error list? Use apt-cdrom first.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an updated install ?

Verify that your sources.list contains one uncommented http or ftp source for each branch you need, and delete the downloaded lists (in /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/) to start fresh.

```
W:GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0
```

This means you have a custom PPA loaded which is not valid for this version - I suspect you upgraded from an earlier version.

Comment: i changed my server-then most of the errors where gone except one

Comment: E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_multiverse_i18n_Index (1)

Comment: solved just had to change to another server!